# How to share JSESSIONIDs with multiple threads?

Tags: jmeter

I am designing a jmeter load test script which is similar to this:

```
Thread - 1
      Login to the application : 1) JSESSIONID cookie is generated in this step
                                 2) CSRF token is generated here
```

.

```
Thread - 2
      Perform operations on the applications : 
                                 1) These steps requires CSRF token in the header.
```

So what I did is extracted csrf token and used bean shell post processor and set it as a property so that it can accessed across all threads. This part is working fine.

**Issue** is that I am unable to share the **JSESSIONID** generated in thread 1 with subsequent threads.

One of the solutions that I tried is that I extracted JSESSIONID from the response header from Thread 1 , then used bean shell post processor and set it as a property and then added HTTP Cookie manager at the test plan level and then added a user defined cookie in which I extracted the cookie
which was set above. This didn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best solution would be moving everything into a single [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), this way HTTP Cookie Manager will automatically manage cookies and you won't have to convert variables into properties
2. It's hard to say why your cookies are not added without seeing your configuration, check out [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. If you have to have the requests under different Thread Groups (although it is not something you should really be doing) - [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-beanshell-jmeters-favorite-built-component) suggests using the following code snippets:

   - in 1st thread group:

     ```
       import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;


       CookieManager manager =

       ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();



       props.put("cookiecount",String.valueOf(manager.getCookieCount()));



       for (int i=0;i<manager.getCookieCount();i++){
                        // code to convert Cookie information to JMeter Properties
           props.put("cookie_name_" + i, manager.get(i).getName());
           …..
       }
     ```
   - in 2nd thread group:

     ```
      import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

      import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
      import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;



      CookieManager manager =

      ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();



      int count = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("cookiecount"));



      for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
             Cookie cookie = new

      Cookie(props.getProperty("cookie_name"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_value"+i), props.getProperty("cookie_domain"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_path"+i), Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("cookie_secure"+i)), Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("cookie_expires"+i)));
      manager.add(cookie);
      }


      JMeterProperty cookieprop =

      ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager");
      cookieprop.setObjectValue(manager);
      ctx.getCurrentSampler().setProperty(myprop);
     ```
3. And last but not the least, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the same code should work in Groovy without any changes

Answer (score 0):

There are few of options available to share the values between threads in same thread group and different thread groups.

1. Use JMeter functions to set and retrieve the values (properties)

TO [SET](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) A PROPERTY :

**${__setProperty(JSESSIONID,JSESSIONID_VALUE,)}**

TO [RETRIEVE](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) A PROPERTY

**${__property(JSESSIONID,DEFAULT_VALUE,)}**

2. Use vars variable with a JSR223 component to work with prosperities

TO SET A PROPERTY
**vars.put('JSESSIONID', 'JSESSIONID_VALUE')**

TO RETRIEVE A PROPERTY
**vars.get('JSESSIONID')**

3. Use Inter [Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) for sharing the values

**NOTE** In your scenario JSESSIONID may be required by the following request in a thread (i.e. user) NOT other threads. Hence you should move all the requests into a single thread group. Create a JMeter variable with JSESSIONID and set header for the subsequent requests.